# How to Split the message in as3?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Hi, am trying to split the word **rtmp://xx.yyy.in/sample/test?22082208,False#&all** this word.The word sample is dynamically added I don't know the count.
I want to split **/sample/** how to do this kindly help me?

Comment: With **input** of `rtmp://xx.yyy.in/sample/test?22082208,False#&all`, what **output** do you want?

Comment: i nedd the /sample/ ie in between the //value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the string.split() method

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29

```
var array:Array = myString.split("/"); //returns an array of everything in between /
```

In your case this will return

[0]->?rtmp:/ [1]->xx.yy.in [2]->sample [3]->test?22082208,False#&all

If you're looking for everything aside from the test?22082208,False#&all part and your URL will always be in this format you can use string.lastIndexOf()

```
 var pos:int = string.lastIndexOf("/", 0); //returns the position of the last /
 var newString:String = string.substr(0, pos); //creates a new string starting at 0 and ending at the last index of /
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr%28%29

Comment: i need this rtmp://xx.yyy.in/sample/ only

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (and almost everything) with regex:

```
var input:String = "rtmp://xx.yyy.in/sample/test?22082208,False#&all";
var pattern:RegExp = /^rtmp:\/\/.*\/([^\/]*)\/.*$/;
trace(input.replace(pattern, "$1")); //outputs "sample"
```

Here is the regex in details:

- `^` : start of the string
- `rtmp:\/\/` first string to find "rtmp://"
- `.*` anything
- `\/` first slash
- `([^\/])` capture everything but a slash until...
- `\/` ...second slash
- `.*` anything
- `$` the end

Then `$1` represents the captured group between the parenthesis.

Comment: @kodaiak i need this rtmp://xx.yyy.in/sample only

Comment: Great! please validate the answer then.

Comment: i have a doubt sir can you please guide me

Comment: @Kodaik Thank you for replying suppose my link is like that(ie extra / is added) "rtmp://xx.yyy.in/sample/link/linktest?22082208,False#&all";that time this mehod is not working how to change ?

Comment: Right, replace the first .*  by [^\/] you'll have: /^rtmp:\/\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\/.*$/